# Dealing with missing elements in xml document

Tags: python, xml, xml.etree

I have some XML, a fragment of which looks like:

```
<osgb:departedMember>
<osgb:DepartedFeature fid='osgb4000000024942964'>
<osgb:boundedBy>
<gml:Box srsName='osgb:BNG'>
<gml:coordinates>188992.575,55981.029 188992.575,55981.029</gml:coordinates>
</gml:Box>
</osgb:boundedBy>
<osgb:theme>Road Network</osgb:theme>
<osgb:reasonForDeparture>Deleted</osgb:reasonForDeparture>
<osgb:deletionDate>2014-02-19</osgb:deletionDate>
</osgb:DepartedFeature>
</osgb:departedMember>
```

I am parsing it with:

```
departedmembers = doc_root.findall('{http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/xml/namespaces/osgb}departedMember')
for departedMember in departedMembers:
    findWhat='{http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/xml/namespaces/osgb}DepartedFeature'
    fid = int(departedmember.find(findWhat).attrib['fid'].replace('osgb', ''))
    theme=departedmember[0].findall('{http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/xml/namespaces/osgb}theme')[0].text    
    reason=departedmember[0].findall('{http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/xml/namespaces/osgb}reasonForDeparture')[0].text
    date=departedmember[0].findall('{http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/xml/namespaces/osgb}deletionDate')[0].text
```

Occasionally either the reason or the date or both are empty, ie, the element is missing, not just has empty content. This is legitimate according to the XSD, but I get attribute errors trying to select the text of a non-existent element. To deal with that I have put the reason and date lines in try, except blocks, like:

```
try:
    date=departedmember[0].findall('{http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/xml/namespaces/osgb}deletionDate')[0].text
except:
    pass
```

This works, but I hate to use except/pass like this, so it led me to wondering if there is a nicer way to parse a document like this where some elements are optional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are interested only in the first element of `findall`, you can replace `findall(x)[0]` with `find(x)`. Besides, if you want to avoid try/except blocks, you can use ternary.

```
departedmembers = doc_root.findall('{http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/xml/namespaces/osgb}departedMember')
for departedMember in departedMembers:
    ...
    date = departedmember[0].find('{http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/xml/namespaces/osgb}deletionDate')
    date = None if date == None else date.text # Considering you want to set the element to None if it was not found
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the issue is not the searching method, rather the referencing of the returning elements when there are none. You can write your code like this:

```
results = departedmember[0].findall('{http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/xml/namespaces/osgb}deletionDate')

if results:
    date = results[0].text
else:
    # there is no element,
    # do what you want in this case
```

Comment: This is certainly cleaner than the try/except. I was partly, wondering though, if this is the best way to be parsing large xml documents, or if I should be using something like xpath within xmltree.

Comment: @JohnBarça, I've found xpath easier to maintain

Comment: @Luis, thanks I'll try that sometime soon. I have had gigabytes of XML to parse in a hurry and getting my head around the various intricacies of the very excellent xmltree library in a short time frame has been fun.